# How to create a multiindex dataframe from two existing singleindex dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have two dataframes that I want to merge and do a multiplication during the merge. Both have one index before and the resulting dataframe should have a multiindex:

location data

```
village   rainfall/year
namea     20
nameb     15
namec     30
```

and time series data.

```
hour    share of yearly rainfall
0       50.00%
1       30.00%
2       20.00%
```

And I am looking for the following dataframe as a result.

```
village     hour    rainfall
namea       0       10
            1       6
            2       4
nameb       0       7.5
            1       4.5
            2       3
namec       0       15
            1       9
            2       6
```

So not only do I want to merge them, but also do some calculations in the merge process. Sadly I do not know how to achieve this. I think [Multiindex from product](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) could be helpful, but I have not figured out how.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You use `merge` with a temporary key to create a cartesian product, then calculate your value, and set_index.

```
df_out = df_loc.assign(key=1).merge(df_ts.assign(key=1)).drop('key', axis=1)
df_out['rainfall'] = df_out['rainfall/year'] * (df_out['share of yearly rainfall'].str.strip('%').astype(float) / 100)

df_out.set_index(['village','hour'])['rainfall']
```

Output:

```
village  hour
namea    0       10.0
         1        6.0
         2        4.0
nameb    0        7.5
         1        4.5
         2        3.0
namec    0       15.0
         1        9.0
         2        6.0
Name: rainfall, dtype: float64
```

Or to return a dataframe instead of a pd.Series, use double brackets:

```
df_out.set_index(['village','hour'])[['rainfall']]
```

Output:

```
              rainfall
village hour          
namea   0         10.0
        1          6.0
        2          4.0
nameb   0          7.5
        1          4.5
        2          3.0
namec   0         15.0
        1          9.0
        2          6.0
```